# Using MySQL: Display all of the Column_Name in upper case, sorted alphabetically without duplicates

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have finished this question, Except I need my query to not show duplicates. How can I do this:

```
SELECT UPPER(surname) 
FROM customers
ORDER BY surname;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(surname) 
FROM customers
ORDER BY surname;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(UPPER(surname))
FROM customers
ORDER BY surname;
```